# setting view's height to be equal to another view's width

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, uistoryboard, nslayoutconstraint

I stumbled across a funny problem in storyboards. I am using constraints. I would like to set a views height to be equal to another view's width. The height and width themselves are not set with constraints and will be set at runtime, depending on the screen size. Can this be done in storyboard?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found it! Ctrl drag from one view to another,click equal heights or widths and double click the constraint. Than just follow this image:[image]

Answer (score 0):

and as a bonus, You can also say:

first height 1/3 of other eight, (for example).. using multiplier with 0.33 value